# What am I talking about? Can you guess

Tags: riddle, wordplay

What am I talking about, you ask?

---

It is the brother of this location.

It has the same parent as this location.

It was the first of the children.

You can find snakes, and googly eyes, and coffee, and scripted coffee and so much more here.

It can help you with these.

But, some help goes unanswered.

If you stack this, it flows over.

---

Is this too hard for you?

**HINTS:*

> It's online.
>  Code

Note: You may have a hard time solving this if you are new to Stack Exchange and if you only have a profile on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer

> Stack Overflow?

It is the brother of this location.

> Stack Overflow is another Stack Exchange Site

It has the same parent as this location.

> Like above, they are both Stack Exchange Sites

It was the first of the children.

> It was the first Stack Exchange Site

You can find snakes, and googly eyes, and coffee, and scripted coffee and so much more here.

> These all refer to languages/things that would be discussed: Snakes = Python, Googly Eyes = Google, Coffee = Java, Scripted Coffee = Javascript

It can help you with these.

> You ask questions about these languages

But, some help goes unanswered.

> Some questions remain unaswered

If you stack this, it flows over.

> A pun to the name, Stack Overflow

Hint:

> Stack Overflow is online, and has to do with code